# HelloWorld Multithreaded C# app

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider the following example taken from http://www.albahari.com/threading/:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class ThreadTest
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Thread t = new Thread (WriteY);          // Kick off a new thread
    t.Start();                               // running WriteY()

    // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("x");
  }

  static void WriteY()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("y");
  }
}
```

How do I modify the code to allow  WriteY() to accept a string parameter so that I can have one thread pass "x" and one pass "y"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;


public class ThreadTest {

    public static void Main () {

        Thread t=new Thread(WriteString);
        t.Start("y");
        Thread u=new Thread(WriteString);
        u.Start("x");

        t.Join();
        u.Join();

    }

    public static void WriteString (Object o) {

        for (Int32 i=0;i<1000;++i) Console.Write((String)o);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the JOIN method needed for your approach and not with the Lamba approach?

Comment: It's not "needed", I just prefer to make sure my threads have exited before dropping out of `Main`.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy I was interested in your reply and just used it to test it, but I have a following question - how can I pass MORE than one parameter? say I wanted to pass through the loop count so it's not fixed at 1000. Thanks

Comment: You have two choices in that case, you can either put the two parameters in an `Object` array and pass them in, and then cast the `Object` to an `Object []`, and then cast say rank `0` to `String` and rank `1` to `Int32`, or you can make a special class (or struct) which encapsulates the data you wish to pass into the function.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a lambda expression:

```
class ThreadTest 
{ 
  static void Main() 
  { 
    Thread t = new Thread (() => Write("y"));          // Kick off a new thread 
    t.Start();                               // running WriteY() 

    // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread. 
    Write("x"); 
  } 

  static void Write(string input) 
  { 
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write (input); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to make three changes.

```
//1. change how the thread is started
t.Start("y");                               // running WriteY()

//2.change how the signature of the method
static void WriteY(object data)
  {
    //3. use the data parameter
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; 1000; i++) Console.Write ((string) data);
  }
}
```