# HelloWorld Multithreaded C# app with double input and output

Tags: c#

Consider the following example taken from [HelloWorld Multithreaded C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721265/helloworld-multithreaded-c-sharp-app)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class ThreadTest
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Thread t = new Thread (WriteY);          // Kick off a new thread
    t.Start();                               // running WriteY()

    // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("x");
  }

  static void WriteY()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("y");
  }
}
```

is there a way to have a function like "static double WriteY (double a)" instead of "static void WriteY()" ?

Comment: That example is pretty old. That's from pre .NET 4.0 era. Look up some tutorials using `async/await` with the Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do with return value of Write method, but I think i get your intention and modified your code snippet to address what you looking for :

```
class ThreadTest
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Task t = Task.Run(() => Write(5));

    // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("x");
    t.wait();

  }

  static double Write(double a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write("y");
        return a;
    }
}
```